# Access last element in XCUIElement

Tags: swift, xcode, coded-ui-tests, xcuitest

In my UI Test, i have this `XCUIElement` :

`XCUIApplication().staticTexts["SUBMIT ORDER"]`

When i make a print debugDescription :

`po print(XCUIApplication().staticTexts["SUBMIT ORDER"].debugDescription)`

There is two element matching :

```
Find: Elements matching predicate '"SUBMIT ORDER" IN identifiers'
      Output: {
        StaticText, {{0.0, 623.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: 'SUBMIT ORDER'
        StaticText, {{0.0, 623.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: 'SUBMIT ORDER'
      }
```

My question is : How can i make a `.tap()` on the last element only ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it using :

```
XCUIApplication().staticTexts.matching(identifier: "SUBMIT ORDER").allElementsBoundByIndex.last
```

Comment: As of Xcode 15, the `.allElementsBoundByIndex.last` works only on the visible elements. Which means that if you want to find the last element in a list and it is offscreen the `.allElementsBoundByIndex.last` will not work. Ex: `let lastCell = list.cells.allElementsBoundByIndex.last` will give you the last visible cell of the `list` element.
I am yet to find a proper way of finding the last element of a list (no matter if it is visible or not)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your testFunc()

```
let app = XCUIApplication()

app.staticTexts.matching(identifier: "SUBMIT ORDER").allElementsBoundByIndex.last
```